# Responsive Square Divs Cross Browser Compatible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page that is 50/50 wide.  The left half has a row with six divs.
Criteria:

- 6 squares must always remain square.
- First 5 squares should have margin/padding to right for separation.
- All six squares must stay on same single row. If I can get that to work i can make the needed adjustments for responsiveness in smaller viewports.
- Cross browser compatible for newest version of ie, chrome, and firefox.

My codepen: https://codepen.io/johnsontroye/pen/zzNVBr

Image:
[image]

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column" style="margin-right: 20px">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-inner">
            <div class="flex-item-inner-content">
              L6
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="margin-left: 20px; border: 1px black solid; height: 500px">

        Other stuff 

  <div>
</body>


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 33.3333%;
    padding-top: 33.3333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 16.6666%;
    padding-top: 16.6666%;
  }
}
.flex-item-inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item-inner-content {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.flex-item:last-child .flex-item-inner {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main trick here is to make the `div` a square.

Normally one set a `width`, the `height` to `0` and a `padding` that equals to the `width`

```css
.square {
  height: 0;
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Now, when we add `display: flex`, we can't use `padding` with percent (Firefox bug) and we can't use height with percent since we used `height: 0`.

To overcome these issues when can use viewport units `vw` instead, and with that we can also use `height` instead of `padding` to keep it squared.

So instead of setting a width like this, `calc((100% / 6) - 10px);`, to spread 6 items equally with a gutter about 10px wide, we use viewport units like this `calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 6) - 10px);`

The `50vw` is half the browser width, the `65px` is the sum of the `container`'s left/right padding, `50px`, plus the `15px` gutter between the `columns`.

This also allows us to skip the extra `flex-item-inner` element, skip using `position: absolute` on the `content` element, and, as we didn't use percent for the height on the `flex-item`, we can do like this to center the content

```
.flex-item-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

---

And the end result is this

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tywyz0ug/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
.column {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 15px);
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 6) - 10px);
  height: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 6) - 10px);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-item-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-item:last-child .flex-item-content {
  color: green;
}

.column .other {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 35px; 
}
.column.left .other {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.column.right .other:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-item {
    flex-basis: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 3) - 10px);
    height: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 3) - 10px);
  }  
  .flex-item:nth-child(n+4)  {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }  
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .flex-item {
    flex-basis: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 2) - 10px);
    height: calc(( (50vw - 65px) / 2) - 10px);
  }  
  .flex-item:nth-child(n+3)  {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L1
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L2
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L3
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L4
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L5<br>L5
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flex-item-content">
            L6
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="other">
      Other stuff - left
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <div class="other">
      Other stuff - right
    </div>
 
    <div class="other">
      Other stuff - right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a pretty complicated solution, but very effective.  Thank you for taking the time to not only solve the problem, but explain the solution in such detail.  If you wouldn't have explained it so well so i could understand what you were doing, i wouldn't have used it.  If I could give you extra points for the explanation I would.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with some fairly simple code, as long as the parent column's width is consistent at 50%-ish, and that the space between squares don't have to be strictly equal to a certain value. The `vw` (viewport width percentage) unit allows for a consistent size to be applied to both width and height of an element.

Here is an example that I boiled down to the fewest elements, and some notes help to move it in to your codebase.

- Experiment with `.flex-item`'s `height` and `flex-basis` (third value of `flex`) to get a size you like.
- No `padding` or `margin` values are needed because `justify-content: space-between;` helpfully calculates that for us.
- Using a `line-height` equal to the `height` of `.flex-item` would allow for an inner element with `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to be centred.

```css
.column {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 48vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 6vw;
  line-height: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 0 0 6vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      L1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      L2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      L3
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      L4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      L5
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      L6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer this.  Unfortunately, this won't work as the space between the squares must always be evenly distributed. I originally did try the flexbox solution you pointed out.  However, the solution for the squares requires an inner div with absolute positioning.  Flexbox does not play nice with that.  Thanks again though.

Comment: An absolutely positioned child should work fine within flexed elements if they have `position: relative;`, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly in Chrome.  However, when i opened it in FireFox the layout was messed up.  The "height: 0" seemed to be throwing it off.  If I removed that it would work in FireFox, but not Chrome.  I spent an entire day trying to get this working with FlexBox and finally had to abandon as i couldn't get it to work.  Not saying it doesn't work, just saying I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only in the latest browsers? [CSS Grid](https://gridbyexample.com/) to the rescue! It's got great support in the latest versions. You may need some vendor prefixes still; check on CanIUse for the details.

Here it is as a fork: https://codepen.io/jackmakesthings/pen/MoJNNV

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px; /* set this to whatever space you need between boxes */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr); /* grid autosizes 6 columns */
}

.row-item {
  grid-column: 1 / 7; /* to span the whole row */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

/* This is a nifty trick for getting those fixed aspect ratio boxes. */
.grid-item:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.grid-item:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive grid changes? Sure! */

@media (max-width: 1000px) {

  /* We just have to change the grid template: */
  .grid-row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  
  /* Unexpected thing I ran into - you also have to change this, or the grid stays big enough to accommodate the old 6-column-sized row-item. Makes sense, but vexed me for a minute!  */
  .row-item {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column" style="margin-right: 20px">
      <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="grid-item">L1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">L2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">L3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">L4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">L5</div>
        <div class="grid-item">L6</div>
        <div class="row-item">some other thing</div>
        <div class="row-item">and another</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="margin-left: 20px; border: 1px black solid; height: 500px">
      
        Other stuff 
     
  <div>
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Exactly what i was looking for.  I know i said i could handle the responsiveness, but i've never used CSS grid before.  Would you mind adding one media query at say a 1000px to switch to two rows of 3 squares each.  Just so i can see the technique.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Updated the snippet and the pen.

Comment: Bingo...perfect in Chrome!  Falls apart in FireFox as is.  However, i assume with the prefixes it'll work in FireFox?

Comment: It should - like I said, you'll want to check http://caniuse.com for the details and resources on how to use it. It's possible there are Firefox bugs with the spec I'm not aware of, but if so they're probably documented there.

Comment: Actually, it's not the CSS Grid that FF doesn't like, it's the CSS for the square.  It's a rectangle in FF.  Any suggestions for keeping it a square in FF?