# Prevent css from changing elements width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

they look normal when i have my windows on full mode(see picture) [image]

But when its on a smaller screen:
[image]

It becomes long shaped. I just want it to stay a square and not change form.

My html and css:

```
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png"/>
</div>
<div id="title">
<h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
 <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
 <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
 <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
 <div class="divInner4">Third DIV</div>

</div>
<div class="divOuter">
 <div class="divInner5">Desseh</div>
 <div class="divInner6">Anna</div>
 <div class="divInner7">Sia</div>
 <div class="divInner8">Lucas</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divOuter {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3,
.divInner4  {
  border: .3em solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  flex:1;}

.divInner1  {
  background:grey;
}
.divInner2  {
  background:grey;
}
.divInner3  {
  background:grey;
}
.divInner4  {
  background:grey;
}

  .divInner1:hover  {
  border: .3em solid white;
}
  .divInner2:hover  {
  border: .3em solid white;
}
  .divInner3:hover  {
  border: .3em solid white;
}
  .divInner4:hover  {
  border: .3em solid white;
}


.divInner5,
.divInner6,
.divInner7,
.divInner8  {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  flex:1;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 24px;
```

A working example can be found at xat.me/madses1996?
I think this has something to do with the fact that im using flex to center things. Is there a way to have it like this but when i shrink my browser it stays square shaped?

I cant seem to edit the boxes individually

Comment: The boxes [don't look square when I try your code](https://jsfiddle.net/90j4m5d5/). Are you using some other CSS that's not shown in your post? It might help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its probably because your screen is smaller than mine, it shrinks the width of the boxes @showdev

Comment: I think the fact that they look square at a certain screen size is just a coincidence. On your live page, box width is set by flex, but height is fixed: `height: 232px`. That height doesn't exist in the code you've posted here.

Comment: Your css rule `.divInner1, .divInner2, .divInner3, .divInner4` has fixed `width` of `150px` and `height: auto`. Have you tried changing the `height` to `150px` also?

Comment: This might generate some ideas: [Responsive Square Divs Cross Browser Compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619678/responsive-square-divs-cross-browser-compatible#answer-44625434).

Comment: Did you try adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items? A default setting is `flex-shrink: 1`, which allows items to shrink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to place those inside of your divs that have the flex property on them.

```
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1"><div class="stay-square">First DIV</div></div>
  <div class="divInner2"><div class="stay-square">Second DIV</div></div>
  <div class="divInner3"><div class="stay-square">Third DIV</div></div>
  <div class="divInner4"><div class="stay-square">Third DIV</div></div>
</div>
```

Set the styling for them so that the height and width are the same:

```
.stay-square { height:150px; width:150px; }
```

You can always use @media to adjust the styling depending upon screen size as well.

Also transfer some of the styling from the outer div to the inner div:

```
.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3,
.divInner4  {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  flex:1;
}
```

to... (I also removed the background styling from the outer divs and placed it in the inner div)

```
.stay-square {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border: .3em solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background:grey;
 }
```

Comment: If you don't need responsivity, you can eliminate the inner elements by using the [`flex` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and setting fixed box dimensions. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4sgyxez/).